# Access "N bits" of a double in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am somewhat new to c# and I am trying to check the status of the first 18 bits in a double.  How can I convert this and write a program to check?

Comment: Have a look at this question first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227376/convert-double-value-to-binary-value then see if you still want to do it.

Comment: (I have yet to find a [good] need to directly access the bits that make up a double .. one can also write a double to an octet stream and then access the stream as a sequence of bits; pay attention to the byte-ordering.)

Answer (score 5):

You should know that the bits you'll get will conform to the [IEEE 754 standard for double-precision floating numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).  These are not trivial to understand, like bits in an `int` are.  Anyway, you can get the value through [BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) or [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9.aspx) (but pay attention to endianness), depending on whether you'd like to work off of `byte`s or a `long`.